# Using getJSON to to fetch RSS feed. I get "SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'"

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to fetch news from here: www.20minutos.es/rss So I'm using this:

```
$.getJSON("http://www.20minutos.es/sindicacion/rss?format=json&callback=?", function(data) {
  alert(data);
})
```

and this:

```
$.getJSON("http://www.20minutos.es/sindicacion/rss?format=xml&callback=?", function(data) {
  alert(data);
})
```

But I get:

> SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
>   http://www.20minutos.es/rss?format=xml&callback=jQuery222028863652776164295_1461795469159&_=1461795469160
>   Line 1

**EDIT**:

after Roland Starke's comment I have used this.

$.get({
  url: "http://www.20minutos.es/rss?callback=?",
  success: function(response) {alert(); console.log(response)},
  dataType: 'xml'
});

but I get:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at http://www.20minutos.es/rss?callback=?.
>   (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).

Comment: @RolandStarke what do yo mean? is it not possible?

Comment: @RolandStarke Im using `$.get` now, but I get another error. I have edited my question.

Comment: The CORS error is relatively self explanatory, you're requesting something from a domain which doesn't allow external access. Just search this site and you'll find a million other questions covering CORS

Comment: Mh do you have docs for the RSS feed? For me the callback and format options dosnt do anything. Your first solution should work if the site listens to the format and callback param.